# How do I get a sum of Var_c across Var_a and Var_b?

Tags: stata

I am trying to find a sum across two variables.

If I have the following data:

```
Name   Commodity        Amount_cmdt

Alex       apple           5
Ben        orange          10
Chris      apple           25
Alex       orange          10
Alex       apple           10
Chris      orange          10
Ben        apple            5
```

I want a final dataset looking like this:

```
Name   Commodity      Amount_cmdt       total_apple    total_orange

Alex       apple           5                   15              10
Ben        orange          10                  5               10
Chris      apple           25                  25              20
Alex       orange          10                  15              10
Alex       apple           10                  15              10
Chris      orange          10                  25              20
Ben        apple            5                   5              10 
Chris      orange          10                  25              20
```

Ultimately, when I have the number of apples and oranges each person has, I can drop the duplicates. But how do I formulate the statement:

> if name = Chris and Commodity =  orange, then total_orange = sum(Amount_cmdt)?

I wrote the following, but it is summing all apples or all oranges irrespective of name:

```
foreach var of varlist Name {
    foreach var of varlist Commodity {
        replace total_apple = sum( Amount_cmdt) if Commodity == "apple"
        replace total_orange = sum( Amount_cmdt) if Commodity == "orange"
    }
}

list
```

Comment: You are likely confusing `sum()` which produces a cumulative or running sum with a function for totals.

Comment: To learn loops in Stata, find an introduction and repeat its examples. In your tentative code you seem to be thinking that `foreach` will induce a loop over the distinct values of a variable, but that is not how it works at all. Each loop of yours is a loop over one item, which happens to be a name, and will be executed once at most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your toy example:

```
clear

input strL(name commodity) amount total_apple total_orange
Alex       apple           5                   15              10
Ben        orange          10                  5               10
Chris      apple           25                  25              20
Alex       orange          10                  15              10
Alex       apple           10                  15              10
Chris      orange          10                  25              20
Ben        apple            5                   5              10 
Chris      orange          10                  25              20 
end
```

The following works for me:

```
bysort name commodity: egen totals = total(amount)
bysort name (commodity): generate totalapple = totals[1]
bysort name (commodity): generate totalorange = totals[_N]

list name commodity amount total_apple totalapple total_orange totalorange, abbreviate(15)

     +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |  name   commodity   amount   total_apple   totalapple   total_orange   totalorange |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  Alex       apple        5            15           15             10            10 |
  2. |  Alex       apple       10            15           15             10            10 |
  3. |  Alex      orange       10            15           15             10            10 |
  4. |   Ben       apple        5             5            5             10            10 |
  5. |   Ben      orange       10             5            5             10            10 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. | Chris       apple       25            25           25             20            20 |
  7. | Chris      orange       10            25           25             20            20 |
  8. | Chris      orange       10            25           25             20            20 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can generalize this for more than two commodities as follows:

```
clear

input strL(name commodity) amount 
Alex       apple           5     
Ben        orange          10                 
Chris      apricot         3
Alex       apricot         4
Ben        apricot         2
Chris      apple           25         
Alex       orange          10              
Alex       apple           10         
Chris      orange          10          
Ben        apple            5             
Chris      apricot         15
Alex       apricot         6
Chris      orange          10                
end

bysort name commodity: egen totals = total(amount)
egen commodities = group(commodity)

levelsof commodity, local(allcommodities) clean
local i 0

foreach var of local allcommodities {
    local ++i
    generate `var' = .
    bysort name (commodity): replace `var' = totals if commodities == `i'
    bysort name (commodity): egen total`var' = min(`var')
    drop `var'
}

drop commodities
```

The modified code snippet will produce the desired output:

```
list name commodity amount total*, abbreviate(15)

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |  name   commodity   amount   totals   totalapple   totalapricot   totalorange |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  Alex       apple        5       15           15             10            10 |
  2. |  Alex       apple       10       15           15             10            10 |
  3. |  Alex     apricot        6       10           15             10            10 |
  4. |  Alex     apricot        4       10           15             10            10 |
  5. |  Alex      orange       10       10           15             10            10 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |   Ben       apple        5        5            5              2            10 |
  7. |   Ben     apricot        2        2            5              2            10 |
  8. |   Ben      orange       10       10            5              2            10 |
  9. | Chris       apple       25       25           25             18            20 |
 10. | Chris     apricot        3       18           25             18            20 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. | Chris     apricot       15       18           25             18            20 |
 12. | Chris      orange       10       20           25             18            20 |
 13. | Chris      orange       10       20           25             18            20 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

@Pearly Spencer gave you what you asked, but the detailed code does show up that that is a very contorted data structure -- which I predict will be very awkward to work with.

Further, you don't need to repeat calculations and then drop duplicates as you can get simple structures directly.

**Note that this destroys the original dataset, so that keeping that original will always be a good idea. Also, we can't comment on what other variables you may have.**

One or both of these layouts are likely to be as or more helpful.

```
clear

input str6 (name commodity) amount 
Alex       apple           5      
Ben        orange          10     
Chris      apple           25     
Alex       orange          10     
Alex       apple           10     
Chris      orange          10     
Ben        apple            5     
Chris      orange          10     
end

collapse (sum) amount, by(name commodity) 

list, sepby(name) 

     +---------------------------+
     |  name   commod~y   amount |
     |---------------------------|
  1. |  Alex      apple       15 |
  2. |  Alex     orange       10 |
     |---------------------------|
  3. |   Ben      apple        5 |
  4. |   Ben     orange       10 |
     |---------------------------|
  5. | Chris      apple       25 |
  6. | Chris     orange       20 |
     +---------------------------+

reshape wide amount, i(name) j(commodity) string 

list 

     +-----------------------------+
     |  name   amoun~le   amoun~ge |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. |  Alex         15         10 |
  2. |   Ben          5         10 |
  3. | Chris         25         20 |
     +-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Helpful and I understand the appeal but the OP will have a difficult time working with the entire dataset given that this will be destroyed by `collapse`.

Comment: I added a warning. I am tempted to invoke your principle that we can't (easily) advise on what the OP doesn't tell us or doesn't ask!